# How can we pass Parameter and Data Provider to same Method in Testng

Tags: java, testing

Hi I am trying data driven in Java. I read excel and passed value to variable "test2" and "test 3" to my test. Also, I need one more parameter "test1" which I am sending from testing.xml. Now on executing below test throws me an error

org.testng.TestNGException: 
The data provider is trying to pass 2 parameters but the method com.xxxxx.xxx takes 3 and TestNG is unable in inject a suitable object

So how to pass parameter and data provider to same method. Thanks

```
/* testdataprovider will return the test2 and test3 parameter value */
@Parameters("test1")
@Test(dataProvider = "testdataprovider")
public void testMethod(String test1, String test2, String test3){}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be terribly wrong (and if I am, I'm sure someone else will give you a better solution); but I don't think you can achieve what you are after, using testNG Guruswamy.
I've just tested your attempt using this dataProvider

```
@DataProvider(name = "login8users")
    public Object[][] login8usersForStackOverflow() {
      return new Object[][] {
       { "user1@gmail.com", "pass" },
       { "user2@gmail.com",  "pass"},
       { "user3@gmail.com",  "pass"},
       { "user4@gmail.com",  "pass"},
       { "user5@gmail.com",  "pass"},
       { "user6@gmail.com",  "pass"},
       { "user7@gmail.com",  "pass"},
       { "user8@gmail.com",  "pass"},      
      };
    }
```

And **passing a parameter called browser** from the XML file. I've noticed that when you use dataProvider and Parameters *under the same @Test annotation*; whether you will get the error that you showed us above or the XMLparameters will be completely ignored (seems that dataProvider supersedes them).
Then here is the test method:

```
 @Test(dataProvider="login8users") 
 @Parameters({"browser"})
 public void login8(String dataProvider1, String dataProvider2) {         

            System.out.println("Email from data provider is..: "+dataProvider1);
            System.out.println("Pass from data provider is..: "+dataProvider2);     

        }
```

And here is the output:

```
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\projects\test\currentTest.xml    

Email from data provider is..: user1@gmail.com
Pass from data provider is..: pass
Email from data provider is..: user2@gmail.com
Pass from data provider is..: pass
Email from data provider is..: user3@gmail.com
Pass from data provider is..: pass
Email from data provider is..: user4@gmail.com
Pass from data provider is..: pass
Email from data provider is..: user5@gmail.com
Pass from data provider is..: pass
Email from data provider is..: user6@gmail.com
Pass from data provider is..: pass
Email from data provider is..: user7@gmail.com
Pass from data provider is..: pass
Email from data provider is..: user8@gmail.com
Pass from data provider is..: pass

===============================================
Regression
Total tests run: 8, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Hence you need to search for alternative solutions. One of them could be to **load the parameter earlier**, (perhaps even in the @BeforeClass)  pass the parameter as global var in your test so you can access it. So something like this for a solution:

```
public static String globalVarScope;


       @BeforeClass
       @Parameters({"xmlParam"}) 
       public void initialSetup(String xmlParam) {

            System.out.println("Parameter from XML is..: "+xmlParam);
            globalVarScope= xmlParam;   
        }   


        @Test         
        public void useMeAnywhere() {         

            System.out.println("Hey, I passed the param earlier and I can use it anywhere now :) ..: "+globalVarScope);    
        }    


        @Test(dataProvider="login8users") 
        @Parameters({"browser"})
        public void login8(String dataProvider1, String dataProvider2) {      

            System.out.println("Email from data provider is..: "+dataProvider1);
            System.out.println("Pass from data provider is..: "+dataProvider2);     
        }
```

So hopefully now you can achieve your desired result, let me know if you get stuck. Here is the final output after running the parameter separately:

```
 [TestNG] Running:
      C:\projects\test\currentTest.xml

    Browser is..: ***chrome***
    Email from data provider is..: user1@gmail.com
    Pass from data provider is..: pass
    Email from data provider is..: user2@gmail.com
    Pass from data provider is..: pass
    Email from data provider is..: user3@gmail.com
    Pass from data provider is..: pass
    Email from data provider is..: user4@gmail.com
    Pass from data provider is..: pass
    Email from data provider is..: user5@gmail.com
    Pass from data provider is..: pass
    Email from data provider is..: user6@gmail.com
    Pass from data provider is..: pass
    Email from data provider is..: user7@gmail.com
    Pass from data provider is..: pass
    Email from data provider is..: user8@gmail.com
    Pass from data provider is..: pass

    ===============================================
    Regression
    Total tests run: 9, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
    ===============================================
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Not a problem Guruswamy, it is a pleasure if I was of any help you. Would be grateful if you can upvote the answer as well (hit the up arrow next to the answer)? Just to get that moral satisfaction - thanks in advance! :)